# Why was Telstar 1 put in a 952 x 5933, 2.6 hour 44.8° MEO orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, communication-satellite, medium-earth-orbit

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telstar_1) that Telstar 1 was put into a 952 x 5933, 2.6 hour 44.8° MEO orbit but doesn't really say exactly why this particular orbit was selected.

Did it perhaps behave roughly like a [Molniya orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_orbit)?

Answer (score 8):

The orbit was chosen as a tradeoff between communication capabilities and the available performance of the launch vehicle.

> Study of available
> boosters
> led to the Delta configuration
> of the Thor
> as the simplest and most reliable rocket for these purposes. Its relatively
> limited lifting capacity
> set a bound of about 180 pounds for a useful orbit.
> This was established
> as: apogee 3450 miles, perigee 575 miles, inclination
> to equator
> 45 °. The apogee is high enough to give good mutual visibility
> between
> northeastern
> United
> States and western
> Europe. Calculations
> for a working
> worldwide
> system
> indicate
> the desirability
> of circular
> orbits at 6000-8000
> mile elevations;
> however,
> these were not achievable
> with the Delta vehicle.

Source: The *Telstar* Experiment, included in [NASA SP-32 Volume I](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19640000959/downloads/19640000959.pdf)

Comment: I see, not just the apogee's altitude, but its location above 45° north latitude between the two "customers". And since it was essentially a short-lived demonstration/test, no need to worry about managing precession like the Molnya orbit.

Comment: @uhoh you'd probably enjoy a read through SP-32.

Comment: Perfect! It's 5:30 AM, I got up to check for clear skies to see comet Leonard but no luck so I've got some nice, quiet reading time ahead of me this morning.

Comment: **update:** Oh I see what you mean! You've linked to volume I above and volume II [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/56137/12102) and both are just chock-full of detailed discussions and photos!

Comment: There is a longer discussion of the orbital choice in the 2nd chapter, but it boils down to what I posted. BTW, there is a volume 3 as well. https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19640001170/downloads/19640001170.pdf

Comment: Four! [I](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19640000959), [II](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19640000973), [III](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19640001170), [IV](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19670002972)

Comment: Thanks! I missed IV. It was marked out in the galley-proofers writing, so I thought it didn't exist.

Comment: @uhoh it appears that Telstar 1 flew a dogleg profile "The
desired higher inclination of 45° was attained by yawing the second and
third stages to the south of the initially established ascent trajectory
plane when the vehicle had arrived at a point where the range was clear
to the south. Since the energy imparted to a spacecraft is reduced by such
yawing, the final apogee or perigee or both will be reduced ."